# Android phone call receiver with voice record in WAV format

Tags: android, communication, phone

Are there alternative apps for receiving phone call in android, that allows you to record the phone call audio (incoming audio) in a raw format such as WAV? I also don't want it to perform any sort of noise reduction or audio enhancement on the incoming phone call audio, even if the phone itself supports such features.

Are there any free apps for android that do this?

Comment: You mean [Call Recorder](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_98)? I've never tested any of those.

Comment: Do those apps replace the built in caller app? I didn't want to download something that just provided an interface for the internal app. Also it should be able to record as a wav file, it seems the android built in call record functionality records in some encoded formats, And it should also be able to bypass any built in noise reduction features of the phone

Comment: As I wrote, I have not tried any of them. Most of them will be additional apps, not replacing the dialer. There are also [Dialer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer#group_76) replacements, but those usually have no recording functionality AFAIK.

Comment: @user17915: it would be interesting what the *"some encoded formats"* are!?

Comment: @DJC: I don't remember right now but two different phone models I tried created files with two different extensions, and they were not wav files so I assume they were some encoded formats

Answer (score 1):

1. first it seems you are asking for 2 different apps!
   a call recorder has usually nothing to do with the dialer. if you don't like the default one, simply chose another one you like...
2. but i guess this question is primarily about the call recorder, so i would recommend [**Call Recorder**](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.axet.callrecorder/) from [axet](https://gitlab.com/axet).

   it has several cool features:

   - you can choose between some well known formats like opus, ogg, flac, **wav**, etc.
   - it is **free** and open source (GPLv3)
   - you can **choose the source for recording** (Auto, System Default, System RAW, Voice Line or Mic), since the audio-streams are handled different from phone to phone.
   - it is completely independent from any dialer
   - has an optional auto-delete feature after a given time
   - additional you can set mono/stereo, the sample rate, the storage path

---

*by the way:* **recording calls in WAV-format usually does not makes sense at all!**

- since for transfer phone-calls are usually encoded with G.722 or even worse, OPUS (the best lossy codec which is known for know) is completely fine for such a task.
- if you can't accept any lossy compression, then use FLAC. - in point of quality it is absolutely identical to WAV, but uses ~45% less storage. and nowadays every recent android-phone has more than enough power to encode FLAC.
- additional if you still want to use WAV because some other system you are using can't play OPUS or FLAC (for sure recent androids can), you have to do something with your other system! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.acr&hl=en) I didn't tried it but it matches you requirements, it is free and developing,

From their google play page,

> Another Call Recorder is a free call recorder application. It is one of the best call recorders in the Play Store and offers tons of features such as:
>
> - Search
> - Grouping recordings by date
> - Auto email (Pro)
> - Auto delete old recordings
> - Marking recordings as important so they don't get auto deleted
> - Multi select, delete, send....